# Evaluating an alternating sum using contour integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3n-1}$$

Using contour integration.

Normally I would use $\pi\csc(\pi z)f(z)$ and evaluate the residue multiply by (-1) and divide by $2$ if the function $f(n)$ were even, in this case it is not even.

I was wondering if I could use contour integration here.

I converted it into an integral.

Without showing the working, (well it was mostly integration and division)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3n-1} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^3}dx$$

I considered a contour $C$ quarter circle, radius $1$ the y-axis is the imaginary axis.

[image: Contour C for integral I]

into section $A,B,D$

With the quad formula, I found three roots.

$x = ${$ \displaystyle \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1 - \sqrt{3}}{2}, -1   $}

Let the poles be called $a,b,c$ respectively, we will only consider $a$ since its the only one in the contour, the radius $R = 1$.

$$\oint_{C} f(z) dz = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx + \int_{B} f(z) dz - \int_{0}^{1} f(iy) d(iy)$$

By the residue theorem I got:

$$\oint_{C} f(z) dz = \frac{4\pi i}{3 + \sqrt{3}i}$$

But I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: should us what you have done so far.

Comment: Okay, let me update

Comment: this sum should be $\frac{1}{9} \left(\log (8)-\sqrt{3} \pi \right)$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner [this?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5En%7D%7B3n-1%7D)

Comment: @Bot, I edited it

Comment: I assume you meant $\dfrac{1\pm\color{red}i\sqrt3}2$.

Comment: why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3n-1} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^3}dx$?

Comment: @Lucian, yes that is the complex root

Comment: Your post says something different.

Comment: @Amad27: You have not chosen the right contour.

Comment: You'd better to consider $f(z)=\frac{z\log(z-1)}{1+z^3}$ to get $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{z}{1+z^3} \text{d}z$. And let $z=1/x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^3}dx&=\frac13\int_0^1\left(\frac1{x+1}-\frac{x-2}{x^2-x+1}\right)dx\\&=\frac13\int_0^1\left(\frac1{x+1}-\frac12\frac{2(x-1/2)}{(x-1/2)^2+3/4}-\frac{3/2}{(x-1/2)^2+3/4}\right)dx\\
&=\frac13\left(\ln|x+1|-\frac12\ln|(x-1/2)^2+3/4|-\frac32\frac1{\sqrt{3/4}}\arctan\frac{x-1/2}{\sqrt{3/4}}\right)_0^1\\
&=\frac13\left(\ln2-\frac12\ln\frac11-{\sqrt3}\left(\frac{\pi}6-\left(-\frac{\pi}6\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\frac13\left(\ln2-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}\right)=\frac19\left(3\ln2-3\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}\right)=\frac19\left(\ln8-\sqrt3\pi\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Are you sure this is contour integration?

Comment: I know this way, $(+1)$ anyway, although it is nearly contour integration.